# Possible to retrieve the method type-safely inside TypeScript decorator?

Tags: typescript

### Target (Desired API)

The `RouteHandler` decorator must store the method on which it appended, to `routesAndHandlersMap` static field declared in `Controller` class:

```js
class ProductsController extends Controller {

  @RouteHandler({
    type: HTTP_Methods.get,
    pathTemplate: "api/products"
  })
  private static async retrieveSelection(_request: Request, response: HTTP.ServerResponse): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void): void => {
      // --- It does not matter for now, just mock to make TypeScript valid --------------------------
      response.statusCode = HTTP_StatusCodes.OK;
      response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      response.end(JSON.stringify([
        { ID: "1", name: "Product1", category: { ID: "11", name: "Cateogry12" }, price: 500 },
        { ID: "2", name: "Product2", category: { ID: "22", name: "Category13" }, price: 1000 }
      ]));
      resolve();
    });
  }

  @RouteHandler({
    type: HTTP_Methods.get,
    pathTemplate: "api/products/:ID"
  })
  private static async retrieveByID(_request: Request, response: HTTP.ServerResponse, routeParameters: unknown): Promise<void> {
    // --- It does not matter for now, just mock to make TypeScript valid --------------------------
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void): void => {
      console.log(routeParameters);
      response.statusCode = HTTP_StatusCodes.OK;
      response.end(JSON.stringify({ ID: "1", name: "Product1", category: { ID: "11", name: "Category13" }, price: 500 }));
      resolve();
    });
  }
}


class Controller {

  public static routesAndHandlersMap: Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>;
  public static getRoutesAndHandlers: () => Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]>;

  public static get routesAndHandlers(): Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]> {
    return Array.from(Controller.routesAndHandlersMap.entries());
  }
}
```

Below `Server` class required the routing data of `Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>` form, but thanks to `getRoutesAndHandlers`, we can easily get all routes and those handlers among `ProductsController` responsibility (same for other controllers):

```js
Server.initializeAndStart({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 1337,
  routing: new Map([
    ...ProductsController.getRoutesAndHandlers()
  ])
});
```

### Problem

We can't get the `retrieveSelection`, `retrieveByID` and other functions if they are exists by `ControllerClass[methodName]` way inside decorator: it's valid from the viewpoint of JavaScript (and works already) but not TypeScirpt (`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Controller'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Controller'.` error will be emitted).

```js
export function RouteHandler(route: Router.Route): (ControllerClass: typeof Controller, methodName: string) => void {

  return (ControllerClass: typeof Controller, methodName: string): void => {

    if (isUndefined(ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap)) {
      ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap = new Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>();
    }

    ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, ControllerClass[methodName]);


    if (isUndefined(ControllerClass.getRoutesAndHandlers)) {
      ControllerClass.getRoutesAndHandlers = (): Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]> =>
          Array.from(ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap.entries());
    }
  };
}
```

Yes, neither `retrieveSelection` nor `retrieveByID` exists on `typeof Controller` because `ControllerClass` is the superset `Controller`, however this superset is unknown at advance same as decorated methods. But how to reach the desired effect?

### Note

I declared the `routesAndHandlersMap` and `getRoutesAndHandlers`in `Controller` class just to make TypeScript know that these static fields will exist on unknown at advance `ControllerClass` superset. But when we call `...ProductsController.getRoutesAndHandlers()`, the `getRoutesAndHandlers` must belong to `ProductsController`, not `Controller`, and also it must refer to own `routesAndHandlersMap`, not `routesAndHandlersMap` of `Controller`. That why we need to make `isUndefined` checks in `RouteHandler`.

### Linda Paiste's solution try

If we'll say TypeScript that the `methodName` is `keyof SpecificController`, `ControllerClass[methodName]` will have type `SpecificController[string] | SpecificController[number] | SpecificController[symbol]`, but we need the `Router.RouteHandler`.

```js
export function RouteHandler<SpecificController extends typeof Controller>(route: Router.Route):
    (ControllerClass: SpecificController, methodName: keyof SpecificController) => void {

  return (ControllerClass: SpecificController, methodName: keyof SpecificController): void => {

    if (isUndefined(ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap)) {
      ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap = new Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>();
    }

    ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, ControllerClass[methodName]);


    if (isUndefined(ControllerClass.getRoutesAndHandlers)) {
      ControllerClass.getRoutesAndHandlers = (): Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]> =>
          Array.from(ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap.entries());
    }
  };
}
```

In line  `ControllerClass.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, ControllerClass[methodName]);`,

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'SpecificController[keyof SpecificController]' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteHandler'.
Type 'SpecificController[string] | SpecificController[number] | SpecificController[symbol]' 
is not assignable to type 'RouteHandler'.
Type 'SpecificController[string]' is not assignable to type 'RouteHandler'.
```

will occur. The `ProductsController` will also brake:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '"retrieveSelection"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prototype" | "routesAndHandlersMap" | "getRoutesAndHandlers" | "routesAndHandlers"'.
```

I want to believe that I missed something.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=181&pc=1#code/PTAEF5NAZBLAjATgQ0QT1AYwPYBMCmEkxJpZ5FlV1NtkAsAFAigC07oAEvgDYAO+RAGc27MeImSp0mbLnyFUpgDMArgDtMAF1jZ1oWEICq6gstjr8uABR9sW-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-tL5Yv-vg2GwaOQ6lvoBPPB4r6TQbd6Z9Wi-PspzHYdX36FIrBXJgWDEUAgWwWFBFANRNBJdQXFgapREUHDcLw-DcOgsBrFAalHhcIRsDghCHEQLAeGQIQRENQwtCEK5QHgWEDC0AByERQkeUoAEdVFgUp2RZUpQEiJh0Omes+GQaVqMQujdluQ0u3jHtVIcIRQVMThn1wNFhFWZA+GOCy+HHeDEI4+yHGM0wzMXPVii02Nu3NJyMWzYodIEAJOAWFZ1i0LZcCESNAoaP4NjmfBpj4BiHBLSVy1iwLRMENAnWQBTaKEAB+AJ8lAPNUEK9FEDpGqMrLdRK0arLQFGbKOo80AvPXXS-IsrRVWOALig2EyzICPyXNMwRsuKAtEIKorBCEKaaPwZbapi24uqjb5ep8whpompD4WsC8FvwXKHim67fAeDjSiEOx1GtO6XtJfAno2rbivWpbqpW4RbkiCBFwtAtpkMfBxwAN2wWBcGXbrDqC47fqB7aRsqoJ8DQVrmqrUBr2aoZ2pXTy1yO0A6VjaYMIALysJzyxGi8c1CpY1k2bYADpDi0YnBtVesXmUN4BEwWBzEwLnwt53B5sq+Weci-m7AeYWVRZIRxcln0ZdgOWwrVqLlc502IqioQ+cwX4HG1obdf1qWjZN7nrbwC3Va96K+ZhIWAhFl2Jbd2XfcVn2rcV23UXRJ3Rb1sPDYjmP1aVjnI4z22iTQoRE9Dg3pbTz2o6z9Obb5lk2ULsWU5L43s-Niuy5zu29AFIPQBD+vi-d5vvdbhX28lZT8Dr5P+9LkeW++XNB-9pTncn13U6byuh++PbNOp9Ge51vvw43tuopxnN4sit58H2BSnEJlqAyvm+760XuRH9cD2nJneDr3jdLTP1vk0d+7N56gAZs7AAYrGAEFRShOEWPcTCuh1BlT0vgEOytIFJxgYgN4Wg-jG2vsApwQhqTqDrAaLQSChAoL0Og9+eCCFEMwCQ1+5DKGGhocgtC2DD5CDwX5P6ggKFUJ4XQtCjCBFCMxigYGYjuG0PoeoTqlMer-10kw2MLCdBsJfk0Th4jlFoXPsvDY7CmgP2JoAixBinCgM-q0CCSsKa720hubRiBhFY1ooo6hJjUE43kv4EmmUybtVAAAMifnY0hb8BGRnGPtIi2FQAAj0JKR8ZlkIaG0KgjCWECLFJKaUuQnZvKgDMMgVQPBHiYAYkxdJmSCwfiQhpb4MJ4A8GNmE1hJQNoGSMqdcyllg6WTshtRAfM-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-alJoB4NgNkH1XrWj5paNjHHcBBvnNDa08NEbIxXPBuSNUXrjzI59N6hBKMaI8bpPj7G2QQHfTmuKHzyhCAyQQAIJ5phnkQMrOKoQATKRZOg+8j5WSqPfaMaJ76LrgP3QUeYqxoDLDZVYsJTV9g-0vO+uKFUpz+fvgGZ0-Z6Qhd9GFwKFVUrIAsElahUWtAPx-u+mdUmENgG6KCPgqVjZEIZTgAgRA6C1bq-VhrjXSBMAac6yGeBVDaAMwGpCXLTAiEPeG74AABCFz7rA5oTCFTe-tBYEkCuYpKKU0qhJ6JZWAwB8wda6zqbeslOlljhn8QgenaNCDQJoa1mV8Bw3wNfNE9L1DWGWCJB62WyM3S0E9cjimuNfSE1DGGYmkYQxzcgMIaWhI-Z44x+AzGJvvr06obrRnQAACYAAMGP5txUi5kgLOYksVWpJiAIPQACM1w3wNV6IAMVVACDKoARH+qeYGO-sWMBMvMk7JwAFh51TkJZPADVDIAMYZAAtDIAK4ZAA-DOTtHPR2ocXzMbUJABWLHCuiekVJ70OXHFBd0-p7rrAbOOflS12TtHRv9c9FF5LmXABmeXoxFdlmlAEcnWOMftXfRWZtM7YPdVG0+syCPwFTfmKffmc2LyLeSql9KvR1ubYLLgTrbFgB+BJ7t2D+3XmHeOxss7F31lwtJbdgAQmgEnz3Xv1ne8hz732FPvXk9x763yHAiOEAEYIoQIgA+-UDkNoOLx8komiPm7H9gDsBvI7a-vArg8h9a5v+Be1McwqHzzSOUehMx9j99eOnABeJ9rinAuac9AZ8zjirOHDs-QGb7nvRyeU715f230vZdO5d8rgIauvcYNApRgF9kkCsx8hIaJyxxkq1H0wVa1EI-kIZ4Ry1K1Jk1IJV28EDnIRlhUL5bg+ZCD5xU8utD0T0tAz0gMzIhAjl5sWATJQB7ApIsAethBOIMAhAapQAIcMBCDCCmBp0Vwx8HNJ9sBp8egSB5NalssegZ1hCJ8p8Z8dBmoZ0gA)

Comment: I can answer some of your questions regarding typescript, but I also feel that having classes where every method is `static` is not a good design and is contrary to the principles of OOP.  Can you create a Typescript Playground that includes all the right types and/or imports for the `Router`, `HTTP`, etc.?  I'd like to play with it a bit and see if I can make something better :)  The issue in your "Note" section re: calling the static method on this current class rather than the parent -- that's something you wouldn't have to worry about with if we were dealing with instances.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to access static methods through main class not child classes, reference to static methods are in fact inherited but they are not properties of the child class itself. Moreover, if you want to access class properties in a `class[method]` way, and the keys are `string` types, you need an index signature in class `[name: string]: Router.RouteHandler`.

[Playground Solution](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/PTAEF5NAZBLAjATgQ0QT1AYwPYBMCmEkxJpZ5FlV1NtkAsAFAigC07oAEvgDYAO%20RAGc27MeImSp0mbLnyFUpgDMArgDtMAF1jZ1oWEICq6gstjr8uABR9sW-Op3IeJsxasA1F6vwAuUA0Aa3VsAHd1AEoAuwcnWBc3fHNLXG8eXwMRDXdU0ABvJlBQRHwtVUR9LTQBbGVQWMdnV1NkjzSfQmJQACIcttSegG4mAF8mJkdVAFsuABU5gAUAfQBZMoALPBFCxmKAczKIXoBxAFE5noAaIobsIS1jnsWAeQBlS5u9rFLkByeAMIAJTOAEE5mdrrc%20KpHuBeosjJ9bgQeGUur0ACJnaAXSFfYrYPg6PQieE9F6LOYASReADk3lDvht8MhcE9OGDMUzijh1JZtID6XSzgDkd8tChMBienMgaCAfjoX9MBsnotwQDOD0xhNGPgAB52RCPaoCUCLVBCKwAKTe9OOluEtvtdOWL3gACt8IKAD4Wq0u%20nLUGIFBoEaMSZG7Am0BmwhO624O3Bj3ewXw3bFADafEQRME1QCD0QFn2AF0Aqm3XT8A8rIsCwITRGxpHo8bTTVE4GU66Q2HkBh4aHwwAeGvLOsN3BNwutgB8Hf1MbjCdAU5nDjnzaLI9uxX96hm8EEh9A-tL5Yv-vg2GwaOQ6lvoBPPB4r6TQbd6Z9Wi-PspzHYdX36FIrBXJgWDEUAgWwWFBFANRNBJdQXFgapREUHDcLw-DcOgsBrFAalHhcIRsDghCHEQLAeGQIQRENQwtCEK5QHgWEDC0AByERQkeUoAEdVFgUp2RZUpQEiJh0Omes%20GQaVqMQujdluQ0u3jHtVIcIRQVMThn1wNFhFWZA%20GOCy%20HHeDEI4%20yHGM0wzMXPVii02Nu3NJyMWzYodIEAJOAWFZ1i0LZcCESNAoaP4NjmfBpj4BiHBLSVy1iwLRMENAnWQBTaKEAB%20AJ8lAPNUEK9FEDpGqMrLdRK0arLQFGbKOo80AvPXXS-IsrRVWOALig2EyzICPyXNMwRsuKAtEIKorBCEKaaPwZbapi24uqjb5ep8whpompD4WsC8FvwXKHim67fAeDjSiEOx1GtO6XtJfAno2rbivWpbqpW4RbkiCBFwtAtpkMfBxwAN2wWBcGXbrDqC47fqB7aRsqoJ8DQVrmqrUBr2aoZ2pXTy1yO0A6VjaYMIALysJzyxGi8c1CpY1k2bYADpDi0YnBtVesXmUN4BEwWBzEwLnwt53B5sq%20Weci-m7AeYWVRZIRxcln0ZdgOWwrVqLlc502IqioQ%20cwX4HG1obdf1qWjZN7nrbwC3Va96K%20ZhIWAhFl2Jbd2XfcVn2rcV23UXRJ3Rb1sPDYjmP1aVjnI4z22iTQoRE9Dg3pbTz2o6z9Obb5lk2ULsWU5L43s-Niuy5zu29AFIPQBD%20vi-d5vvdbhX28lZT8Dr5P%209LkeW%20%20XNB-9pTncn13U6byuh%20%20PbNOp9Ge51vvw43tuopxnN4sit58H2BSnEJlqAyvm%20760XuRH9cD2nJneDr3jdLTP1vk0d%207N56gAZs7AAYrGAEFRShOEWPcTCuh1BlT0vgEOytIFJxgYgN4Wg-jG2vsApwQhqTqDrAaLQSChAoL0Og9%20eCCFEMwCQ1%205DKGGhocgtC2DD5CDwX5P6ggKFUJ4XQtCjCBFCMxigYGYjuG0PoeoTqlMer-10kw2MLCdBsJfk0Th4jlFoXPsvDY7CmgP2JoAixBinCgM-q0CCSsKa720hubRiBhFY1ooo6hJjUE43kv4EmmUybtVAAAMifnY0hb8BGRnGPtIi2FQAAj0JKR8ZlkIaG0KgjCWECLFJKaUuQnZvKgDMMgVQPBHiYAYkxdJmSCwfiQhpb4MJ4A8GNmE1hJQNoGSMqdcylljiWDCAfWyflEB8z8o5DasyTquUEIuawkRspdJ6ZgPpejQCCz8kM3AM0zJklAOs8Gl04qgBAmgPmygobWAyU4VpZk%20aLX0oZY5IyhA2T5k0Ms9Z1kbO6ls3pDx%20mCwGYhI5JzVrrICLc8cF8ZlzI2gstSaLEJwrohWCGo0ShlAqPoW59zHnPKyW02ZHz6xfJxb8yy-yXmwCBZEEF29QWqG6eCwhey2TfJWXRc6NKAa0SxQ4Di41BWisEOK-AOKwbgAhhS15sqaWwp%20X860WhrA0slSM9ltwcwhOsTKpZG0cVJL1BUuMKF8l6AwTi3VG0zVyrBh0q65RKigHHNPY2KrslIW4Y4aKzSXmBsQGsgNVKASNLWqAP1mBo1mQ4kVKK9UFIP2iKABGSNwYFAvMm2V-KnV6rDZSsysbGJCBzGmvAGaJ7suKHtZJeoYIcCBPWL6uTUIFJ6UUspg6h3iCYMgeApZlL1LjXBRS3aPUNC5ds0AY6J2CiEFy6GOqlJoB4NgNkH1XrWj5paHde7cDZvnNDa08NEbIxXK2-aISXrjxnZ9N6hB51owAcOXdbIIBXIJXFCF5QhAZIIAEE80wzyIGVnFUIAJlIsnQfeR8rJVFXNGNEq5F1wHXIKPMVY0BlgUqsWEpq%20wf6XiuXFCqU4SP3wDM6fs9JKO%20mo4FCqqVkAWCStQ%20jWgH4-yueyh9bawDdFBHwVKxsiEOpwAQIgdAlPKZU6ptTpAmANOrZDPAqhtCgZaRGjRcRQ1FvUt1AAAss2aiBrAEoTCFTe-tBYEkCuYpKKU0qhJ6JZWAwB8y6f0zqbeslviMTQJoQlmV8Bw3wNfNE9r1DWGWCJB6AmZ03S0E9Wd76D1fQvVDGGN6kb4ovMgMI3GhI5aPeu%20Am67NXOA6oAz4HQAACYAAMHXXNxTo5k0jOZ2MVWpJiAIPQACM1w3wNV6IAMVVACDKoARH%20puYD%20DfWMBN8MjbGwAFh21Nk1vRADVDIAMYZAAtDIAK4ZAA-DONtrPR2ocXzMbUJABWLrD2hukVG70O7HFDs9AW79rAa39gbfKl9sbbWgf-dO5dm7ABme7oxHtlmlAEcbXWOvtSuRWC8owm3Y-2sUKzFqRkNfAQ5%20Yp9%20YuYvO55KXH0q9F8-5gsuA9NsWAH4EbwXm2heKOFyLpRouxYAEJoBG8l1L9Z0udsy9lt971X2Hu%20tChwIjhABGCKECIBXsBXthrm5GBbwF8komiPmu79jOsBvI7aBOBcVcwoSxX%20A%20a1fq4B3ZzWwOhM691q5fWnCkeG99ibB2ZsA6WytkHYOtth-G5Nv7kfYfXdu0jlHz2Ahvax8kuK%20POq6hSYwM3QkaLlmDpZOyiy5UYrFdZty4z8CTJstXzF8yMHmuxSMtZF9bh8wH-Odn%20mzMCzKIculPz1muZYCZUA9gpJYEM1SkQ8AMBCBqqACrGAB8D6YBWQ1JfSSoct9ga3PQSCvtqQJno7Kzcn6tzbnQzV2VAA)

The solution is not complete yet, you must rework it to use instances of SpecificControllers instead of static methods. The current approach presented in this playground is not valid. Controllers should be singleton instances that are referred from within routing map.

Answer (score 1):

You get errors when you try to access a method name on the `ControllerClass` because you are allowing any `string`.  We need to only allow a `methodName` which is a property of the class.

We want those method names to include those of the current controller and not just the parent `Controller`.  We will do this by making the returned function a generic that depends on the controller type.  Typescript interfaces only include the `public` properties of any object, so you will have an issue with keeping the `ProductController` methods `private`.  You will need to make them `public` for this to work.

```
export function RouteHandler(route: Router.Route) {

  return <T extends typeof Controller>(ControllerClass: T, methodName: keyof T): void => {
...
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/AwQr1N)

Regarding this issue in your "Note" section:

> But when we call `...ProductsController.getRoutesAndHandlers()`, the `getRoutesAndHandlers` must belong to `ProductsController`, not `Controller`

This feels like an inherent limitation of using a class where every method is `static`.  I would recommend rethinking this structure and trying to have some sort of instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and help. I'll try to get some time to prepare the TypeScript Playground. For now, I tried your solution. Very sorry about it does not work, but I hope that I just missing something. I updated the question and I will write the comment again once TypeScript playground will done.

Comment: Sorry for make you waiting. I prepared the TypeScript playground as you asked. The URL is too long, so please check it in the end of question filed. About make methods/fields of controller non-static: it's O'K to do it if no force of library user to create the instance of controller. E. g. I want to keep `ProductsController.getRoutesAndHandlers()` instead of
`new ProductsController().getRoutesAndHandlers`, but if `ProductsController.getRoutesAndHandlers()` using
 private constructor internally to get same effect, it's all right.