# The non-static method does not see the non-static fields of same class when using decorator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Below function intended to be used as decorator in the inheritors of `Controller` class:

```js
function RouteHandler(route: Router.Route): (controller: Controller, methodName: string) => void {

  return (controller: Controller, methodName: string): void => {

    /* 〔 Theory 〕 In this case, the "methodName" must be in "controller" instance as long as this function is being
    *     used as decorator for "Controller" inheritor. */
    const handler: Router.RouteHandler =
        (controller as unknown as { [methodName: string]: Router.RouteHandler; })[methodName];

    controller.setRouterAndHandlerPair(route, handler);
  };
}
```

This decorator function must add the the `route` object and handler function to `routesAndHandlersMap` of inheritor of `Controller` class:

```js
class Controller {

  private readonly routesAndHandlersMap: Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler> = new Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>();

  public setRouterAndHandlerPair(route: Router.Route, handler: Router.RouteHandler): void {
    this.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, handler);
  }

  public getRoutesAndHandlers(): Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]> {
    return Array.from(this.routesAndHandlersMap.entries());
  }
}
```

The usage is:

```js
class ProductsController extends Controller {

  @RouteHandler({
    type: HTTP_Methods.get,
    pathTemplate: "api/products"
  })
  private async retrieveSelection(_request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In real application, there are multiple controllers basically.

### Problem

When creating the instance of `ProductController`:

```js
const productController: ProductsController = new ProductsController();
```

the `RouteHandler` calling `controller.setRouterAndHandlerPair(route, handler);`. Then, the `controller.setRouterAndHandlerPair(route, handler);` calling `this.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, handler);` but `this.routesAndHandlersMap` is `undefined`. It causes the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`.

[Fiddle](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=40&ssc=5&pln=40&pc=51#code/PTAEF5NAFAnBTAtAgjgVwJYILbwHbwAuAzpGeRZVdTbXfQ-QLABQIoinoASgPZqF4sUADM0eAMaEMvPAEMANhkIBPDpw2at2nbr36Dhoztb402UAAkAKtegB9ALJEAFrwAmxUAG9WoUADmRBCgAEQA4gCi1qEANH6gAA68xIQhodAA8gDKMQns+PwBeKK8wni8AO6sAL6srPK4xIlyEvA8-ILCviwJ8AAeybBpqontfALwxACCeO6WcnMKQsSOcokha4kAPBOCsR2TC0tCAHz1LP4DQyMqY4eCIT3+-qPwAFxWtg7OhG6eAG4Ev4Wn9rPBsIkFHJBJ9UrAMHgAkDLi90EIVNA5LA5LgusQAPyfbygADaLRxeKEADlcR9QPDEQEALpwwgIpEA0A1FH+HkXK6DMq3e57eBrQgSFxPYGgFyLdzLWCfMXHRVCXkvWCdeBYylEFYqnV6un4zX83qo67C0BvB7wNVKkIACll-lQaCmhBV8HRqQOCGasmI9O4U2SeBDAeN2NNhvtJqpsGICQAlBBTjBtdgMCHtgA3XgYdynFF9IXDW13cYx-X4p5kgDW8BUbI5LLbTK5FrqbDAxgHg6Hw5Ho+0Fwk0OIXgAwrJ2bwFE6eglEgj8zD2gg5O5ZAo1NrJjM5o6VltPltdjrYAA6MUHMW31UKpWZ8CgAiVUCXx93nUP68-yOF8zmdVMy1RRI0AAIyUCQGSIR9ZnmEDYCxLBnUPWF7Sff85VQo1Jlw4CTlgVNPkLYsfFlCRg0XeAbwUXgAmdUINFCcCaLo5ZGOY50-lzTjUX8WjI3o3iWIE4gbywqZkNPZMtnA0B2HEdx4BERF4HcUAAEJ9NlKSZJ1Y8UNI1Z1hvENCEwvD5VIoS+QFJIYLgwJEJM+TUOIMDPmmWAcRUbZSRwoD9lC59SNAZlM2eLUiDQWASn8wKbxEbN+JcXNjKPLzzK2G98HZDApjAxzuVqC5WDESRpFke0FNsyZCK6ML4HI0BnVEhclyET45zwHqlQOPF-lpXBOyRdNwEzSidJXVEEEIRKSi6+dtV65VQAGoahBG1wPHG+lGSmiiix0mbqMtF4VIAKlAQAUBlAawXHgMo1EAVAZQAASRKKTQAkOQo1tV6wlGw66VCUBsDQVJQGg9pETCbqNqVKHEVSRY2lAIHQCYpEca8f6aqkGQSlzeH4CZWV7pu2HtMJ0B1NonFCDKUphFCHbUaEdG8FehE2dvUBbuALjIzSez1S239IuliA3ReNbBp54RcfERsKkqEpcZJUlwfcI7Jo7CKdQU7tU31g7DbpZkIJulHFyVKyPKIvLpfQ2AmvCqWlXKnsJynLw4A8NApGIbmnaEUABkEOZZ3WqPumcgABOWlWdOLXmrT4bDsJxrekoJCHiYSkhhFxwUhaFsNCdYMGANdQ-D0IEhqVNV3XTdCZUSRQCWhF4HzeBsngZZSdkZ17A9L0fT9Ev+-DYNQyXyN2s+EOczzObYtldgbwPtvKstVhRLhpv3DDwhI82jftUv8Ob6dd9PyzZuSCfoQwJRIA)

### How `getRoutesAndHandlers` will be used

Below `Server` class will create the controllers instances and call `getRoutesAndHandlers`. All that user need to do is refer to controllers classes as below:

```js
Server.initializeAndStart({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 1337,
  routing: [ ProductsController, ProductsCategoriesController ],
  logger: ConsoleApplicationLogger
});
```

Comment: The decorator is executed on the prototype, but `routesAndHandlersMap` is set/instantiated in the constructor. So this line `this.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, handler);` is executed before `this.routesAndHandlersMap = new Map();`.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you for the comment. Is what I want is possible? I [have 
 implemented this functionality before with static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66348899/4818123), but has been advised to make all methods non-static.

Comment: Yes, move the methods and the Map out of the Controller class and into a module. But ultimately there's the question, do you need any classes? I don't see any shared state between routes; so every method is basically standalone. And without classes there's no point for a decorator. So why not simply a `function registerRoute(type: HTTP_Methods, pathTemplate: string, handler: Router.RouteHandler): void;`

Comment: @Thomas "I don't see any shared state between routes; so every method is basically standalone." - in this minimal example is such us. But in real example each inheritor of controller could refer co common class fields, e. g. injected data base provider. "And without classes there's no point for a decorator." - please check the updated question ("How getRoutesAndHandlers will be used" section).